# Passing Dynamic Input to Child Component showing as undefined In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Sidebar inside a component like below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
         <!--Main Content-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
         <app-sidebar [qdyk]="dyk"></app-sidebar>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In the parent component I set the dyk property:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Load the current question
    this.currentQuestion();
  }

// Load the current question
  currentQuestion() {
    // Get the current question from the API
    this.questionService.getCurrentQuestion().subscribe(res => {
      // Load the question to angular
      this.loadQuestion(res);
    });
  }

loadQuestion(sequence: any) {
    // Load the whole sequence object...
    this.sequence = sequence;
    this.question = this.sequence.currentQuestion;
    this.dyk = this.question.didYouKnow;
    console.log(this.dyk);
}
```

The above console log returns the text I was expecting from the API, but when I try to pass this down to the child I get an undefined

```
@Input() qdyk: string;

ngOnInit() {
    // Show DYK Value from Parent
    console.log(this.qdyk);
  }
```

Passing a string value and bypassing the question loading works and outputs the string to the console passed from parent to child (for example: `<app-sidebar [qdyk]="'Some Text'"></app-sidebar>`) - it's just when I pass in the dynamic value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong hook to check the values as they are being delayed and initially it will be `undefined` . Use `ngOnChanges()` -

```
@Input() qdyk: string;

ngOnChanges() {
    // Show DYK Value from Parent
    console.log(this.qdyk);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is common cause when calling the child component the value of `dyk` is undefined. As `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook runs only when it loads, the console.log() gave undefined. But once `loadQuestion()` is called on parent component, it will be reflected on childcomponent but `ngOnInit()` won't run again, so it isn't be displayed on the console. If you had declared the `this.dyk` in ngOnInit of parent component instead of `loadQuestion()`, the console.log() will surely display your dynamic value.
That's why when you directly passed a string as input it was shown in console.
To console the values on child component use `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hook